# array multidimensional get index by given number

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, c#-3.0

I have multidimensional 3*3
for example user input is 4 that calculate need to be array[1,0] 
user input is 5 that calculate need to be array[1,1] 
user input is 2 that calculate need to be array[0,1] 
user input is 3 that calculate need to be array[0,2]

how can i accomplish this in the best way in c#
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `n` rows and `n` columns, then the `k`-th element in the order that you described is given by:

```
row = (k - 1) / n
column = (k - 1) % n
```

If you have `m` columns, then:

```
row = (k - 1) / m
column = (k - 1) % m
```

As you can see, it's only the number of columns that matters (unless you also need to detect potential index out of bounds errors, then you also need the number of rows).

Comment: I'm just impressed that you understood the question! :)